# R recode values in dataframe with condition

Tags: r

i have a dataframe

```
  namer  None  namei  ...   None
  None   None  Na  ...   namej
   .
   .
  named  namev None   ...   Na
```

and i want to replace all Nones with 0 and everything else with 1
i tried to use lapply with the following function

```
 fu = function(x){
 if (x=="None")
     0
 else
     1}
```

but it throws an error, how can i fix this

Comment: More directly you're getting an error because you didn't include curly brackets in your `if () { outcome1 } else { outcome2 }` code. More generally, you don't need to do this because R vectorizes by default. you can just do `ifelse(x == "None", 0, 1)`

Comment: Or `+(x != "None")` should work.